# Jetpack Composable isn't updating(redrawing) after the viewModel is updated

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a mutableStateListOf(ReturnItemExamples) and each of the objects in the list are being displayed in a LazyColumn.

The thing I am having trouble with is once I update the quantity using the OutlinedTextField, and it calls the API (on the viewModel) to update the record, after the API returns successful results and updates those to the mutableStateListOf(ReturnItemExamples) list, the update to the quantity, isn't being shown in the OutlinedTextField.  I believe that the update is happening and that it is triggering a redraw by the composable, because I have other fields that are being updated, the only field I have trouble is the OutlinedTextField.  That is the only one that isn't updating on screen.

Here is the data model that has the quantity property:

```
class ReturnItemExample (
    val itemCode: String? = null,
    val itemDescription: String? = null,
    var quantity: Int = 0
)
```

Here's the viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ReturnsViewModelExample @Inject constructor(
    val app: Application,
    val authToken: String,
    private val repository: ReturnsRepository,
) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val returnItems = mutableStateListOf<ReturnItemExample>()

    private fun updateReturnExample(quantity: Int, index: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {

        // Call to an API here returns the updated ReturnItemExample object and I update it here
        // with a function that sets the item from the API response to the item in the array at
        // the specified index
                    returnItems[index] = API.response

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the listview:

```
@Composable
fun ReturnsListViewExample(
    viewModel: ReturnsViewModelExample,
) {

    val itemIndex = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        Box() {
            LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
                itemsIndexed(viewModel.returnItems) { index, _ ->
                    ReturnItemViewExample(
                        viewModel = viewModel,
                        itemIndex = index
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the composable that show the OutlinedTextField I am having trouble with:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun ReturnItemViewExample(
    viewModel: ReturnsViewModelExample,
    itemIndex: Int
) {

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val itemData = viewModel.returnItems[itemIndex]
    var testDisplayQuantity by remember { mutableStateOf(itemData.quantity.toString()) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "Test Quantity",
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = testDisplayQuantity,
            onValueChange = { testDisplayQuantity = it },
            textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 14.sp),
            maxLines = 1,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                .onKeyEvent {

                    if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        if (validQuantity(testDisplayQuantity.toInt())) {
                            viewModel.updateReturnExample(testDisplayQuantity.toInt(), itemIndex)
                        }
                    }
                    true
                },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    keyboardController?.hide()

                    if (validQuantity(testDisplayQuantity.toInt())) {
                        viewModel.updateReturnExample(testDisplayQuantity.toInt(), itemIndex)
                    }
                }),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following line in your code:

```
var testDisplayQuantity by remember { mutableStateOf(itemData.quantity.toString()) }
```

It creates a new state variable of type String and initializes it to `itemData.quantity.toString()`. After this initialization, **there is no more connection to the original itemData object**. It is completely independent.

I recommend two steps to resolve this problem:

1. You need to introduce logic that updates the quantity of an item in the ViewModel. When you modify it directly on `itemData`, it will have no effect. Jetpack Compose cannot detect when you modify one property of a state object. Instead, it can only recompose once a reference changed.
2. You can either completely remove the additional `testDisplayQuantity` state variable or you can introduce logic that refreshes the `testDisplayQuantity` variable whenever the `itemData` changes.

**Step 1)**

In order to update the quantity of an item, create a ViewModel function similar to this:

```
fun updateQuantity(index: Int, quantity: String) {
    returnItems.set(index, returnItems[index].copy(quantity = quantity.toInt()))
}
```

We replace an instance in the list on position index with the [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/set.html) function and assign a new instance with updated quantity using the [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) function. Jetpack Compose detects the change and will recompose the LazyList.

Then call it in `onValueChange` like this:

```
onValueChange = { 
    viewModel.updateQuantity(itemIndex, it) 
}
```

**Step 2)**

Replace all occurences of `testDisplayQuantity` with `itemData.quantity.toString()` and delete the variable.

Alternatively, you can use a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) to update your `testDisplayQuantity` variable whenever the `itemData` changes:

```
val itemData = viewModel.returnItems[itemIndex]
var testDisplayQuantity by remember { mutableStateOf(itemData.quantity.toString()) }

LaunchedEffect(itemData) {
    testDisplayQuantity = itemData.quantity.toString()
}
```

---

As a side note, please consider to pass the item itself to the `ReturnItemViewExample` Composable instead of the index in the list. It results in cleaner code and makes your local `itemData` state variable redundant.

```
items(viewModel.returnItems) { item ->
    ReturnItemViewExample(
        viewModel = viewModel,
        itemData = item
    )
}
```

Then update your Composable signature as follows:

```
fun ReturnItemViewExample(
    viewModel: ReturnsViewModelExample,
    itemData: ReturnItemExample 
) {
    //...
}
```

Also, you should update your `ReturnItemExample` class as follows:

```
data class ReturnItemExample (
    val itemCode: String? = null,
    val itemDescription: String? = null,
    val quantity: Int = 0
)
```

When you have a var inside of a data class, this will usually result in things not working in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Thank you for these approaches, I will try them now.

Comment: Replaced with itemData.quantity.toString(), then when I test it, the OutlineTextField doesn't work anymore. It is first shown with 3, then I tap on the field and tap the backspace and then typing a 2, the 3 isn't deleted as you would expect, instead the cursor just moves to the other side of the 3, as if I tapped an arrow key instead of the backspace.  Then if I try to type the 2, you would expect that it would change to 23, but I just get the cursor moving back to the other side.

Comment: So I've got to figure out how to use itemData.quantity.toString(), but still get the Outline text field to work.  Here's the value and onChangeValue
value = itemData.quantity.toString()
onValueChange = { itemData.quantity.toString() = it }

I have also tried adding a string called displayQuantity to my ReturnItemExample object and seeing if I can manipulate that instead of the quantity field, but it acts the same as the above, the only difference is I don't have to call .toString() on it, but either way it still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my post to also explain how to call the ViewModel function. I hope it is clear now!

Comment: I finally ended up with Approach 2, adding the LaunchedEffect.  Once I did that the UI started updating.

Answer (score -1):

Use `MutableStateFlow` for this it's an official way to notify composable state

you can refer this blog [Exploring Kotlin Flows in Jetpack Compose: A Powerful Combination](https://medium.com/@nrvrangapariya186/exploring-kotlin-flows-in-jetpack-compose-a-powerful-combination-2604f9b5ea4e)

Comment: Nice article, but it only shows how to use the MutableStateFlow in the composable by using viewModel.dataState.collectAsFlow().  Can you give an example or link to how you set up dataState in the ViewModel?